# A finite group that is not a symmetry group

Tags: group-theory, symmetry

A symmetry is an isometry of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Given a subset $S$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$, the symmetry group $Sym(S)$ is the group of all symmetries that map $S$ to $S$. My question is, is there an example of a finite group which is not isomorphic to any symmetry group? Or, is every finite group isomorphic to some symmetry group?

Comment: Does [this math.overflow post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/993/is-every-finite-group-a-group-of-symmetries) answer the question?

Comment: (Actually, probably not, as that one proves that it is the symmetry group of some polytope, but it need not be a $2$-dimensional object...)

Comment: Aside: That seems to be a very narrow definition of "symmetry."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the comments a link was posted giving an $n$-dimensional construction, but in your question you ask for the group to be the group of symmetries of a 2-dimensional set. In this case, the claim is false, essentially because the group of isometries of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is too small.

Specifically, which elements of the isometry group have order 3? One can check these are all of the form 'rotation by $2\pi/3$ or $4\pi/3$ about some point,' from the classification of isometries of $\mathbb{R}^2$ (they're all translations, rotations, reflections, or glide reflections; one can easily check that none of those can have order 3 besides the rotations just mentioned).

Take $G = \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z} + \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}.$ It has 9 elements, 8 of which have order 3. All elements commute. If we tried representing it as a subgroup of the group of isometries of $\mathbb{R}^2,$ we'd run into the following problem: Rotations about two different points don't commute!

Comment: It is interesting to wonder if every subgroup of the group of isometries of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is the group of symmetries of some set. The easiest candidate would be take $S$ to be the set of all points fixed by that subgroup, but then there's a tricky part of showing that $S$ doesn't have any additional symmetries outside of $G.$ I wonder for what vector spaces $X$ we get this sort of behavior, where the fixed set of some subgroup of isometries has no additional symmetries.

Comment: Not clear why it would be the elements fixed by that subgroup. If an isometry fixes three non-linear points on the plane, it fixes the plane. You'd really want to take the orbit of a particular point as $S.$ But then the translations, which are a proper subgroup, has the orbit the whole plane, so that $S$ doesn't work.

Answer (score 6):

Being a finite subgroup of $\textrm{Isom}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ is a very special property. First I will give as simple example of a finite group which is not such a subgroup, and then bellow describe all finite groups of "symmetries" as you have defined them.

Consider $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$ with generators $a$, $b$, $c$. Each generator must act as an isometry of order 2, but there is a very explicit classification of isometries of $\mathbb{R}^2$: they must be

1. the identity (order 1)
2. a reflection (order 2)
3. rotation (order 2 only if a rotation by $\pi$)
4. translation (infinite order)
5. glide reflection (infinite order)

So $a$, $b$, and $c$ must be reflections, or rotations by $\pi$. We also know that these generators must commute. Two reflections commute if and only if the mirror lines intersect at right-angles. Two rotations by $\pi$ commute if and only if they are equal (otherwise their product is a translation along the line through their centres of rotation). Finally a reflection and a rotation by $\pi$ commute if and only if the mirror line passes through the centre of rotation (otherwise their product is a glide reflection along the line orthogonal to the mirror through the centre of rotation).

This doesn't leave many options. We could let $a$ and $b$ be reflections in intersecting orthogonal mirrors, and $c$ be the rotation by $\pi$  centred on this intersection point, but then $c=ab$, and $\langle a,b,c\rangle\cong\mathbb{Z_2}\times\mathbb{Z_2}$, which is not the group we were after. It follows no group of isometries of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$.

---

### The general picture

If $G$ is finite, then it globally fixes a point in the plane. To see this, let $x\in\mathbb{R}^2$ be any point, and let $y$ be the "centre of mass" of the orbit $Gx$ which is compact since $G$ is finite. Then $G$ fixes $y$.

Groups of isometries which fix a point contain only rotations about that point, and reflections in mirrors through that point. It follows easily that the only finite groups of isometries of the plane are

- the trivial group, which is the group of symmetries of, for example, the shape "F" drawn in the plane
- the cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}_n$, which is the symmetry group of a ratchet wheel with $n$ teeth
- the dihedral group $\mathbb{D_n}$, which is the symmetry group of a regular $n$-gon.

Thus, these are the only finite groups of symmetries of $\mathbb{R}^2$, and every finite subgroup of $\textrm{Isom}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ is the group of symmetries of a set $S\subset\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Do you happen to know if this is the only obstruction to being the symmetry group of a set, i.e if $G$ is some subgroup of $\text{Isom}(\mathbb{R}^2),$ is it precisely the subgroup fixing some set $S\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: I have updated my answer above to answer your question for finite groups. You can do more or less the same thing for infinite discrete groups of isometries. These have been classified, they are the wallpaper groups (together with the degenerate cases: those fixing a point (finite groups) and those fixing a line (isomorphic to either the infinite cyclic or infinite dihedral group). All these groups are the groups of symmetries of some set $S$, and you can choose $S$ to be [very pretty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallpaper_group).